# Property of definite integral

Tags: definite-integrals

What is $$F'(x)\text{ if } F(x)=\int_{0}^{x}g(t)dt$$ I was thinking that $$F'(x)=g(t)\big|_{0}^{x}$$ is this correct?

Comment: $F'(x)$ is simply $g(x)$ (assuming that $g$ si continuous).

Comment: Why not $g(x)-g(0)$?

Comment: [Fundamental Theorem of Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus)

Comment: Apply Leibnitz test. It gives a good result.

Comment: $F(x)= \int_0^x 1dx=x$, $F'(x)=1$, not $F'(x)=1-1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $G$ is an antiderivative of $g$, i.e. if $G'=g$, then you can write
$$ \int_0^x g(t) \,\mathrm dt = G(x)-G(0).  $$
By differentiating, you therefore obtain
$$ \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} \int_0^x g(t) \,\mathrm dt = \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}(G(x) - G(0)) = G'(x) = g(x),  $$
where $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} G(0) = 0$ since $G(0)$ is a constant.

Comment: Nice answer (+1)

Comment: @RobertZ Thanks for the kind words!

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is wrong, unless $g(0)=0$. By the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, $F'(x)=g(x)$.